# Strategies for Prediction : Forecasting Production

Tags: r, time-series, machine-learning, forecasting

As an example : I have data for production of a plant for a period of 2 years.

Data set: Jan 2013-Jan 2015

I have created a machine learning model to predict production.

The sales are to be predicted for the upcoming month. I can use the data from the previous month, or use the data from the previous 12-24 months. The minimum RMSE does not conform to one particular method. How can I create two separate models and combine them in a way to minimize error. I want to capture long term trends as well as catch short term (previous month's) nuances.

Let me know if this is clear

Comment: What's the temporal structure of your data? Hourly? Daily? Weekly? Monthly? Quarterly?

Comment: I have Daily data with some 'N' features. Used those 'N' features to create a model using randomforests to predict production there after.